# Binding conconst value to a table

Tags: wpf, xaml

Suppose I have a table 4x4, no more/less rows and columns. The values are from the calculations in the code.
[image: here]

What is the best way to create it and bind the data?
Using datagrid or [table](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/4-examples/21-wpftables.htm)?

I used datagrid for columns but not sure how to deal with rows.

```
<DockPanel>
        <DataGrid Name="dgTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="IVR" Binding="{Binding IVR}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Payment" Binding="{Binding Payment}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Call" Binding="{Binding Call}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
```

**Edit:** 10:08 am 11/03/2014

Based on the Mike's comment, I made a change.

```
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1">IVR</TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2">PAYMENT</TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3">CALL</TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1">SUCCESS</TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2">FAIL</TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3">TOTAL</TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```

Then how to bind the values?

Comment: A data grid is probably overkill if you have a such a small, fixed set of values.  I would just set up a `Grid` and place text blocks in each cell, bound to the appropriate values.  A DataGrid may be more useful if you want the user to be able to copy the values to the clipboard such that they can be pasted into directly into Excel with the layout intact.  If that's not a requirement, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, I updated the code. How to bind the values?

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding IVR}" />`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike Strobel, I used `Grid` plus textboxs.

```
   <DockPanel Margin="20">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1">IVR</TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2">PAYMENT</TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3">CALL</TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1">SUCCESS</TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2">FAIL</TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3">TOTAL</TextBox>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IVR_S}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PAYMENT_S}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CALL_S}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IVR_F}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PAYMENT_F}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CALL_F}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IVR-T}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PAYMENT-T}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CALL-T}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```